# please help with ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow

How to fix error ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
Im thinking the error is from too large for dtype or an infinity.

This is an imbalanced multiclassification neural network with 15 classifications. With 78 input dimensions. 
Program is here https://pastebin.com/dru0pfEH
[image: error]

```
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("C:/Users/bam88/train.csv", header=0, 
dtype=object).drop_duplicates()
dataset = dataframe.values
x_train = dataset[:,0:78].astype(float)
y_train = dataset[:,78]
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("C:/Users/bam88/test.csv", header=0, 
dtype=object).drop_duplicates()
dataset = dataframe.values
x_test = dataset[:,0:78].astype(float)
y_test = dataset[:,78]

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y_train)
encoded_Yone = encoder.transform(y_train)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_yone = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Yone)
#encode our testing set
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y_test)
encoded_Ytwo = encoder.transform(y_test)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_ytwo = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Ytwo)
(dummy_yone.sum(axis=-1) == 1).all() == True
(dummy_ytwo.sum(axis=-1) == 1).all() == True

smote = SMOTE('minority')
x_smotetrain, y_smotetest = smote.fit_sample(x_train, dummy_yone)
print(x_smotetrain.shape, y_smotetest.shape)
```

Comment: Check if you have missings in the df https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame